# Adding GeoRSS feed as point layer using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, xml, georss

There may be a simple answer, but I have been looking on the internet for answers and trying different things.

I want to display [this RSS feed](http://osom.cfa.vic.gov.au/public/osom/IN_COMING.rss) as a point layer in OpenLayers 2.11.

Can anyone please give me some code that may help?

Comment: I have tried this:-  var urlObj = "http://osom.cfa.vic.gov.au/public/osom/IN_COMING.xml";
    rss = new OpenLayers.Layer.GML("GeoRSS", urlObj, {format:
      new OpenLayers.Format.GeoRSS({'xy': true})});    and I'm getting an errorloadinggml message.

Comment: I have got the rss feed points to display now.  Can someone please help me to format the points to different colors??  Also I would like to click on points and have the feed information show.  Can someone please help??

Comment: rss = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("CFA RSS", 
    {projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.Script({
                url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
                params: {q: "select * from xml where url='http://osom.cfa.vic.gov.au/public/osom/IN_COMING.rss'"},
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoRSS(),
    parseFeatures: function(data) {
                    return this.format.read(data.results[0]);
                }
    }),
    });